# html - how to make <a> clickable in border?

Tags: html, css, button, click

Say I have a 
`<a class="myclass" href="foo.htm">Click Here</a>` 
and in css something like this:

```
.myclass
{
border: 2px solid #000;
padding: 1em;
}
```

so the `<a>` looks like a button but it only operates when clicked **on** the text, not in the whole box. How can I make so that the box also "catches" onClick?

Answer (score 3):

Block will not work well unless you float the element and give it a fixed width. I think "inline-block" would work better.

```
.myclass{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/2tmzL/

Browser support for inline-block is pretty good: http://caniuse.com/inline-block

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the anchor tag around another container element

```
<a class=".." href=".."><div>Click here</div><a>
```

Answer (score 0):

< a > is an inline , you have to transform it to a block, try this

```
.myclass:
{
  display:block;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the css property display: block or inline-block (depending the case...) for your a element.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be able to click the entire link. Make sure you remove : after .myclass. Also if it's still not working you may like to try adding display:block;

Alternatively in html5 you can wrap the a tag around a block element. This will work in older html though it's not correct.

```
.myclass
{
    border: 2px solid #000;
    padding: 1em;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that a's are inline elements, and padding doesn't work the way we expect with inline elements. Change the a's to a block level element, and everything should work as you expect (note the removal of the ":" in the CSS declaration, that shouldn't be there):

```
.myclass {
   display: block;
   border: 2px solid #000;
   padding: 1em;
}
```